# Terminal command for removing all named files except for one

Tags: terminal, file, macos

In `Terminal.app`, how can I delete all files of a certain name except for one extension?  For example if I have:

```
File.docx
File.ppt
File.pdf
File.xlsx
File.out
File.app
FIle.otherextension
File2.docx
File2.ppt
File2.pdf
File2.xlsx
File2.out
File2.app
FIle2.otherextension
```

all in one directory, how can I delete all of the `File` ones except for `File.out`?

Expected `ls` output at the end:

```
File.out
File2.docx
File2.ppt
File2.pdf
File2.xlsx
File2.out
File2.app
FIle2.otherextension
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will delete all files named `File` (and **only** those) within the current folder, **except** ones with extension `.out`:

`find . -type f \( -iname "File.*" ! -iname "*.out" \) -delete -maxdepth 1`

If you want to perform this operation recursively (traversing all subfolders), remove `-maxdepth 1`:

`find . -type f \( -iname "File.*" ! -iname "*.out" \) -delete`

The **i** in -**i**name performs a case-insensitive search, so `file.*`, `FILE.*`, etc. will be deleted as well. Likewise, `file.OUT` would be spared.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ls File.* | fgrep -v .out | xargs rm
```

This corresponds to your description: select all files named `File` with some extension, remove the one with extension `.out` from the list, and delete the others.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ksh`'s extended glob.

```
rm !(*.out|File2.*|FIle2.*)
```

Which says in words- remove files that do not end in `.out` or begin with `File2.` or begin with `FIle2.`

`ksh` extended glob is also available in `bash`. You must turn on the option with `shopt -s extglob`. This solution will fail if you exceed ARG_MAX.

Make sure that you are in the directory where these file exist or you could unintentionally remove files.